# Laravel Carbon not converting the desired format

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

From datepicker, I have received a date e.g.

```
Sat Sep 15 2018 09:29:18 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I did the following but it show me the below error message:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $receivedDateFromdatePicker);
echo $date;
```

> > Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data

Comment: You can format a date from view if you are using jquery datepicker like: `var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();` OR `$("#issue_date").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", });`

Answer (score 0):

just use the simple way:

`$date = new \Carbon\Carbon($receivedDateFromdatePicker);`